# What does version 255.255.255.255 for winmd files indicate?

Tags: c#, .net, windows-8, windows-runtime

I noticed that most (all?) **.winmd** files have a version of **255.255.255.255** like:

**Windows, Version=255.255.255.255, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null**

Metro apps have a reference to such assemblies with this version number.

---

Further the Windows.winmd itself references:

**mscorlib, Version=255.255.255.255, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089**

However, an assembly with this version number does not exist, as far as I know.

Does this version number have a special meaning? Is there any documentation for this?

Comment: Presumably they picked a version number that's meaningless for development, and they'll use a real one when it comes to release. Perhaps to prevent [a repeat of Windows 3.95](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2004/02/13/72476.aspx)?

Comment: @ta.speot.is: Nope, it's an arbitrary number.  It could have been anything.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

ECMA 335 assemblies need to have a version number.  But the windows runtime type resolution algorithm doesn't use the version number, so the team creating the winmd format chose an arbitrary version number of 255.255.255.255 for the assembly version number.

That helps to ensure that nobody attempts to use the .Net type resolution algorithm when doing type resolution (it's not perfect, unfortunately some tools still use the .Net type resolution algorithm).

Oh and the mscorlib reference is a pro-forma reference - ECMA 335 requires that all typeref's have a corresponding assemblyref and the WINMD file format chose to use typerefs to certain ECMA 335 types as indicators of a specific type.  For example, the winrt "enum" construct is represented as a type which extends "System.Enum" - for a winmd file the "System.Enum" part is just a string (it could have been anything), and cannot be resolved to a real type.  That string is represented in metadata as a typeref and typerefs have to have an assemblyref - we chose to use the mscorlib version of System.Enum as the assemblyref for the enum because it was convenient.

Comment: Btw, if you ever see a comment that a .winmd file "needs to be strong named", that's an indication that you're using a tool set that understands .Net assemblies but not windows runtime metadata.

Answer (score 3):

Keep in mind that the .winmd files contain metadata for the WinRT interfaces.  Windows can't assume that any particular version of .NET will be used.  Windows 8 will be around a lot longer than .NET 4.5

Nor can a .NET project assume it will run on any particular version of Windows.  It should work just as well on Windows 8 as on Windows 10.

So interpret 255.255.255.255 as "any version".

Comment: This makes sense. But wouldn't the WinRT interfaces themselves change as time passes and so I would think it would be better to give the winmd files an explicit version number.

Comment: WinRT versioning is done differently.  Don't know how, it was mentioned "it's different" in a Build conference session but without further explanation.

Comment: @HansPassant: Every windows runtime type has a Windows.Foundation.Metadata.VersionAttribute attribute which indicates the version in which the type was introduced.

Comment: @logicnp: Btw, winrt interfaces are immutable - they cannot change as time passes.