# What's with XAML clr-namespace versions of 255.255.255.255?

Tags: xaml, xamarin.forms, uwp-xaml

Is a XAML `clr-namespace` version of 255.255.255.255 something special or just an arbitrary value?

While trying to play with some Xamarin.Forms Native View embedding, I ran across this [Consuming Native Views](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/platform-features/native-views/#Consuming_Native_Views) sample on the Xamarin docs. Inside the XAML, it adds a Windows namespace like this:

```xml
<ContentPage
    ...
    xmlns:win="clr-namespace:Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;assembly=Windows,
    Version=255.255.255.255, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null,
    ContentType=WindowsRuntime;targetPlatform=Windows"
    ...
>
```

The `Version` on that namespace looks a little like a networking subnet mask, so it caught my eye. Does that particular version have some special meaning or have they just filled it in because it expects a value there? Are there other special values that can go in there?

Answer (score 1):

The Standard of ECMA 335 defines the Common Language Infrastructure (CLI) in which applications written in multiple high-level languages can be executed in different system environments without the need to rewrite those applications to take into consideration the unique characteristics of those environments.

> ECMA 335 assemblies need to have a version number. But the windows runtime type resolution algorithm doesn't use the version number, so the team creating the winmd format chose an arbitrary version number of 255.255.255.255 for the assembly version number.
>
> That helps to ensure that nobody attempts to use the .Net type resolution algorithm when doing type resolution (it's not perfect, unfortunately some tools still use the .Net type resolution algorithm).

For more detail please refer to [What does version 255.255.255.255 for winmd files indicate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10411168/what-does-version-255-255-255-255-for-winmd-files-indicate).